# Magento 2: Why do Some Tasks Not Show Up in Task List?

Tags: magento2, frontend, grunt

If I [install the npm project and grunt config](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html) that ships with Magento 2 -- I'm able to run commands like

```
grunt clean
grunt clean:var
etc.
```

However, if I run `grunt --help`

```
Grunt: The JavaScript Task Runner (v0.4.5)

/* ... */
Available tasks
 black-list-generator  Custom task.                                            
     clean-black-list  Custom task.                                            
               deploy  Custom task.                                            
          mage-minify  Minify files with a various compressor engines *        
               static  Custom task.                                            
              default  Custom task.                                            
                 prod  Custom task.                                            
              refresh  Custom task.                                            
        documentation  Alias for "replace:documentation", "less:documentation",
                       "styledocco:documentation",                             
                       "usebanner:documentationCss",                           
                       "usebanner:documentationLess",                          
                       "usebanner:documentationHtml", "clean:var", "clean:pub" 
                       tasks.                                                  
         legacy-build  Alias for "mage-minify:legacy" task.                    
                 spec  Custom task.                                            

/* ... */
```

The `clean` task does not show in the list of avaiable tasks.

Why is this?  Is `clean` not a task?  If not, what is it?  If so, is there a way to get a full task list?

A shorter version of this question: What's the deal with grunt?

Answer (score 2):

Grunt is configuration oriented task runner, which means that you can create just a config and it will be automatically converted to a task, which apparently seems to be ignored by `--help` flag, to your convenience ofc :)

To help you get how Grunt works. You have to combine all these files and directories to get the full image of available tasks:

- `Gruntfile.js` - that's the main file
- `dev/tools/grunt/tasks` - tasks itself
- `dev/tools/grunt/configs` - config files which are taken as tasks (both
  JS and JSON)
- `dev/tools/grunt/tools` - helpers functions

PS. Yes, I hate Grunt so much.